# Create shapes with radial symmetry using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapes

I am trying to generate symmetrical circular images using python, but I couldn't find an easy way to do it.

Here is an example sort of what I want:
[image]

So far, I listed the processes, but I couldn't find an easy way to implement them.:

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a polar plot, then it's just a matter of calculating the coordinates. For this, I am using `np.linspace` and I combine a division of the trigonometric circle, the same points shifted by 10°, and zeros:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import chain

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.grid(False)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

n = 6

# division of the circle
a = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n+1)

# angles
theta = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, np.zeros(n+1), a+(np.pi/180*10))))

# distance to center
r = np.tile([1,0,1], n+1)

# plotting line
ax.plot(theta, r)
# plotting fill (needs an extra (0,0) point)
ax.fill(theta+[0], list(r)+[0], alpha=0.2)
```

example:

[image: custom shapes polar plot]

##### example with a loop

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3, subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})

axes = axes.flatten()

def plot_shape(ax, n=3, delta=np.pi/180*10):
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

    a = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n+1)-delta/2
    theta = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, np.zeros(n+1), a+delta)))
    r = np.tile([1,0,1], n+1)

    ax.plot(theta, r)
    ax.fill(theta+[0], list(r)+[0], alpha=0.2)

for i in range(len(axes)):
    axes[i].set_title(f'n = {i+1}')
    plot_shape(axes[i], n=i+1)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: example with loop]

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I loop the "n=1 to n=11" to output multiple images in one run?

Comment: @haben I made a function that takes an axes and n as argument, then a simple loop does the trick. I'll update the answer if you don't manage

Comment: I tried to create a loop but it plots all of the shapes in a single figure. I'm in new to plotting and excuse my ignorace. would you please update the answer? I appreciate it.

Comment: @haben I provided a complete example. Btw, out of curiosity, what is the purpose of those graphs?